# save_post hook is not called when post is saved

Tags: php, wordpress, api

In wordpress whenever new blog post is created all post details need to be send to third party api. I'm using **save_post** hook for this but not sure whether it's getting called or not
This is what i've done so far

```
     add_action( 'save_post', 'new_blog_details_send');
    function new_blog_details_send( $post_id ) {

  //getting blog post details//
        $blog_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $blog_link = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
        $blog_text = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);

        ///Sending data to portal////
        $post_url = 'http://example.com/blog_update';
        $body = array(
                'blog_title' => $blog_title,
                'blog_link' => $blog_link,
                'blog_text' => $blog_text
        );

        //error_log($body);

        $request = new WP_Http();
        $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );


    }
```

Not sure how to log or debug in wordpress.Any help would be appericiated Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check whether your third party working using static contents ?

Comment: yeah it's working fine

Comment: this code added in functions.php right ?  if your are in local server , print the $response and exit .   Then check by saving the post.

Comment: It works fine in local server but doesn't working properly on remote server? what could be reason for that

Comment: did you try printing the $response ?

Comment: Yeah i tried & it's working fine in local server but on remote server hook is not getting called @sarath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the problem by taking the alternative hook for **save_post**. Used **publish_post** instead & with higher priority & it worked

```
    function new_blog_details_send( $post_id ) {

  //getting blog post details//
        $blog_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $blog_link = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
        $blog_text = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);

        ///Sending data to portal////
        $post_url = 'http://example.com/blog_update';
        $body = array(
                'blog_title' => $blog_title,
                'blog_link' => $blog_link,
                'blog_text' => $blog_text
        );

        //error_log($body);

        $request = new WP_Http();
        $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );

 }
add_action( 'publish_post', 'new_blog_details_send',10,1);
```

Comment: @Rituparnasonowal parthgoswami51094@gmail.com